# hover image and show the text beside

Tags: html, css

```
<img src="" alt="" class="aa">
<img src="" alt="" class="bb">
<img src="" alt="" class="cc">
<img src="" alt="" class="dd">
<div class="a">text</div>
<div class="b">text</div>
<div class="c">text</div>
<div class="d">text</div>
```

I want to click on the seperate img and bind the div(aa to a, bb to b, cc to c, dd to d ) to show by only css

```
.a {
display: none;
}
.aa:hover + a {
display: block;
}
```

and infortunately it doesn't work, I didn't know what is wrong

Comment: instead of `+` use `~` like `.aa:hover ~ .a { display: block; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you want. But there are errors in your code.

1. The + selector selects the element that comes immediately after the parent. You need to write the following:

```html
<img src="" alt="" class="aa">
<div class="a">text</div>
<img src="" alt="" class="bb">
<div class="b">text</div>
```

2. "a" is a class and its selector must start with a dot, like that: .a And you need to write the following:

```css
.aa:hover + .a {
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: what if I can't change the format of HTML are there any solutions for this?

Comment: @40468300 Yes. The ~ selector. It selects all elements going after parent in yout case is should be .aa:hover ~ .a In details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator